# Mongoose ^4.13 find and process all async

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying to find what I need, but most of it was from 2012-2013, so I decided to ask.

I have an array of emails like this:

```
const emails = ['email1', 'email2', 'email3', ...]
```

Then I want to search the database and get all documents 1 by 1 by the given array, and work with each one separately. Something like this:

```
User.find({email: loop through all emails})
.on('document', document => process document)
.on('error', err => process err)
```

Also, I'd appreciate if the solution is fast.

Comment: map reduce  or aggreggation , 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: @KevinAB I'd like to do it through `mongoose`. Can you give an example?

Comment: [async.each](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) may also be useful.

Comment: http://excellencenodejsblog.com/mongoose-aggregation-count-group-match-project/